# Mismatch in Latitude-longitude obtained from Google API

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, google-api, geocoding, latitude-longitude

I was trying obtain "latitude-longitude" information for multiple addresses using google API. However, I observed that for few addresses I was getting different "latitude-longitude" values over a period of time. Can "latitude-longitude" change over a period of time? If yes, why? Or is it just a bug (or may be due to an update) in google API?

Answer (score 0):

latitude-longitude pair define a geo-location in earth, and that point is generally not moving. If you get different results for same address information, then it is the service which for some reason gives different values. Thus do check that what actually is happening, either you are giving a different address, or the service is interpreting it diffferently. Best way to determine what has happened is to see what values were actually used in the query, and check all data given in replay (many APIs are giving also the address detail for the location given as result value)